# How do i change the size of a drawing on illustrator without affecting the line thickness

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixelation

Hi im new sorry if this is a stupid question. I have a logo made up using the pen tool and blob brush tool and have all the thicknesses right however when i try re-sizing the whole logo the line thicknesses all change. I was wondering how i could fix this?

Comment: switch off scale stroke

Comment: @ilan actually it sounds like Jojo needs to turn the setting on so they scale with their illustration

Comment: @Ryan I am not sure we can clearly understand the question.. anyway playing with stroke scale is worth it..

Answer (score 1):

When you scale something you have the option of scaling strokes, or not:
[image]

Turning it on means a 200% scale would turn a 1 point line weight to a 2 point line weight. Leave it off and a 1 point line weight remains a one point line weight no matter what your resizing.

Answer (score -1):

each line is a path . so you select the path and modify its thickness by varying the **stroke** reading in the upper left area , just below the main toolbar.

Comment: The person already has their illustration complete and is asking how to scale the illustration without running the line work